# Show upload file progress to dropbox

Tags: java, swing, file-upload, dropbox-api, event-dispatch-thread

I need to display on the window (`JFrame`) the upload progress of the file that is currently being upload to dropbox.

I have looked at multiple examples and most of them are working with dropbox API v1.

I need to show progress of upload file to dropbox using API v2.

The coding that I am using for uploading a file is shown below:
(How can I manipulate this to display file upload progress.)

```
try
        {
            File file = new File("C:\\... Storage location of file on local system");
            //reads file as input for the method to dropbox
            InputStream fileupload = new FileInputStream(file);
            //path in dropbox account to store the file 
            // if want to store it in root just put '/'
            //if want to store file in a folder '/foldername/'
            client.files().uploadBuilder("/" + file.getName())
                    .withMode(WriteMode.OVERWRITE)//always overwrites the existing file in the dropbox folder
                    .uploadAndFinish(fileupload);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File uploaded to dropbox");
        }
        //exception handled
        catch (DbxException e)
        {
            //error message for uploading file to dropboxcloud
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to upload file to Cloud \n Error: " + e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to upload file to cloud \n Error: " + e);
        }
```

Please could someone help me out with displaying this progress as the file is being uploaded?

Comment: 1) I removed the Netbeans tag because your IDE has nothing to do with this. 2) *"Please could someone help me out with displaying this progress as the file is being uploaded?"* SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk, so please try some things then ask a *specific* question. 3) But a tip here is a) Do the 'heavy lifting' task using a `SwingWorker` so as not to block the EDT. b) A `JProgressBar` would be the component in which to display ..progress. 4) Voting to close as 'too broad'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you, I will take that into consideration and I will give the SwingWorker a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API v2 Java SDK now offers progress listeners for uploads and downloads. This has been released in v3.0.9:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/releases/tag/v3.0.9

There's an example of using it with with the uploadAndFinish method ( https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxUploader.html#uploadAndFinish-java.io.InputStream-long-com.dropbox.core.util.IOUtil.ProgressListener- ) for an upload here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/upload-file/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/upload_file/Main.java#L50

It works the same way with file downloads; the download method ( https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxDownloader.html#download-java.io.OutputStream-com.dropbox.core.util.IOUtil.ProgressListener- ) optionally takes a ProgressListener parameter the same way.